# Regex for multiple number variations + alphanumeric suffix

Tags: regex

How can i write a regex pattern to match all variations of floats and integers (seperated by a dot or comma) with a two characters alphanumeric suffix (with a space or not) in a long text something like this:

```
34MB
34 MB
34.3MB
34,3MB
34.30MB
34,30MB
34,30 MB
5MB
5 MB
1.024MB
1.024 MB
1,024MB
10,67MB
10.67MB
```

Is it possible? I tried something like this but not working

```
/(\d+(.|,\d+)?\s\MB|KB|GB|TB)/
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe this does the trick:

```
(\d+(?:[.,]\d+)?)\s?([MKGT]B)
```

**EDIT:** Honoring the post of @FailedDev, you might append a `\b` to match word boundaries. Thus, it won't match `1200MBPS`, but `1200MB`.

Comment: I would modify it slightly to `(\d+(?:[.,]\d+)?)\s?([MKGT]B)` so it puts the values and units in capture groups: http://rubular.com/r/B0KC8WJe8Q

Comment: Also there is no need to escape dots when they are in a character class.

Comment: thank you for answer and comment, it's too close that what i need. Only problem is does not matching 1,200.6KB but i forgot to write, it's enough.

Comment: @Edigu - you could fix that with `(\d+(?:[.,]\d+)*)\s?([MKGT]B)` but it allows mixing dots and commas.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like this:

```
/\b\d+(?:[.,]\d+)?\s*[KMGTPE]?B\b/
```

Word anchors ensure that you don't match this inside something else.

Comment: @hochl Yeah, I have stumbled upon forgetting this many times, so it became a lesson to me :)

Answer (score 1):

This might work, depends on what the boundry condition context is:

`/\b(\d+(?:[.,]\d+)?\s?[MKGT]B)\b/gi`